# (AWK) Creating a username column using the characters from first name and last name columns

Tags: bash, awk

trying to achieve an output of having a new column after the last which uses the first letter of the first name and the rest of the last name. what is the proper way to type this out using awk?

INPUT:

```
Vincent Nguyen
David Pham
Bobby Hill
```

Output:

```
Vincent Nguyen vnguyen
David Pham dpham
Bobby Hill bhill
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
awk '{print $0,tolower(substr($1,1,1)$NF)}' file
Vincent Nguyen vnguyen
David Pham dpham
Bobby Hill bhill
```

Could be shorten some to: (but less robust)

```
awk '$0=$0FS tolower(substr($1,1,1)$NF)' file
```

---

Updated to support longer name like:

```
Bobby Bigfoot Hill
```

gives

```
Bobby Bigfoot Hill bhill
```

Answer (score 2):

based on your example, try this `sed` oneliner:

```
sed -r 's/(.)\S* (.*)/& \L\1\2/' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
Vincent Nguyen
David Pham
Bobby Hill

kent$  sed -r 's/(.)\S* (.*)/& \L\1\2/' f
Vincent Nguyen vnguyen
David Pham dpham
Bobby Hill bhill
```

Comment: Fails if user has more than first/last name.

Comment: @Jotne to be honest, I am expecting this comment to come. :D that's why I wrote `based on your example`. Yes, if there are more name parts, like middle name etc. the sed one-liner needs to be adjusted.